# Use unmapped property in query: Invoking lambda expression vs "duplicating" property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have an ASP.NET MVC code first project with an `Item` table, and I have lots of queries where I need to filter or order by items' properties.
Here is the (simplified) partial class containing database columns:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Squares = new HashSet<Square>();
        this.Sales = new HashSet<Sale>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Item")]
    public virtual ICollection<Square> Squares { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Item")]
    public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the (simplified) related partial class, containing functional properties:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int UsedQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            var nbUsedInDomain = Squares != null ? Squares.Count() : 0;
            var nbForSale = Sales != null ? Sales.Sum(s => s.Quantity) : 0;
            return nbUsedInDomain + nbForSale;
        }
    }

    public int AvailableQuantity
    {
        get { return Quantity - UsedQuantity; }
    }
}
```

I think I could use the `UsedQuantity` and `AvailableQuantity` properties directly in my queries using `ToList()` but I would like to avoid this for performances issues.
Thus I think I would need to create something like that for my queries:

```
public static Expression<Func<Item, int>> GetAvailableQuantity()
    {
        return i => i.Quantity -
            (
                (i.Squares.Any() ? i.Squares.Count : 0) +
                (i.Sales.Any() ? i.Sales.Sum(s => s.Quantity) : 0)
            );
    }
```

But this is somehow "duplicating" the `AvailableQuantity` property in the other `Item` partial class, and this would mean that every property used for filtering or sorting should also be duplicated.

I read I could `Invoke` the lambda expression the retrieve the result for one particular instance, so should I invoke the expression from functional partial class so the code would not be duplicated ? Is there any performance issue? Should I keep the properties duplicated ? Or any other solution allowing to use those unmapped properties in query without performance issues?

Comment: Are you using entity framework? Please add more detailed tags!

Comment: Sorry, yes I am actually using EF ;)